# matchcollection timeout

Tags: c#, regex, timeout

I am using matchcollection while parsing to the html. but this solution take a long time and it fails sometimes. I am thinking if i set matchcollection timeout this trouble will solve. How can i set the matchcollection's timeout  ? (framework 4.0)

```
anchorPattern[0]="<div.*?class=\"news\">.*?<div.*?class=\".*?date.*?\">(?<date>.*?)?</div>.*?<a.*?href=\"(?<link>.*?)\".*?>(?<title>.*?)?</a>.*?<(span.*?class=\".*?desc.*?\">(?<spot>.*?)?</span>)?"
    MatchCollection mIcerik = Regex.Matches(html, anchorPattern[i], RegexOptions.Compiled);
    if (mIcerik.Count > 0)
          ListDegree.Add(i,mIcerik.Count);
```

Comment: Do you know that the most upvoted answer in Stack Overflow recommends to avoid to use Regex as a parsing tool for HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I've heard the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the go-to HTML/DOM parser for .NET.

Comment: Yes,I know it. But html source code can't be correct then htmlparser better isn't than. For example sometimes no closing tag in html text. so i prefer to use regex.

Comment: @alikoyuncu a good HTML parser is more likely to deal with invalid HTML properly than any regex you could come up with.

Comment: When you say "it fails sometimes" - what do you mean, i.e. is there an exception message if so, can you give details please.

Comment: @m.buettner Nothing else to add.

Comment: @Barry Kaye there isn't an exception.When I look in myIcerik that  seing "Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized."

Comment: Do you have some test data you could provide?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression has way too many `".*?"` and probably the number of possible combinations get near to "infinite" for some of your inputs. Try using the atomic group `"(?>.*?)"` instead, to automatically throw away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group. That will at least make all regular expression parsings take a finite time.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

anchorPattern[0]="<div.*?class=\"news\">.*?<div.*?class=\".*?date.*?\">(?<date>.*?)?</div>.*?<a.*?href=\"(?<link>.*?)\".*?>(?<title>.*?)?</a>.*?<(span.*?class=\".*?desc.*?\">(?<spot>.*?)?</span>)?"

MatchCollection mIcerik = Regex.Matches(html, anchorPattern[i], RegexOptions.Compiled,timeout);
 
 
if (mIcerik.Count > 0)
      ListDegree.Add(i,mIcerik.Count);
```

The `Timespan` parameter establishes a timeout interval to match all objects. Or you can use `Regex.InfiniteMatchTimeout` to indicate that the method should not time out.
[MSDN regex.Matches()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0)